# Calculate amounts in interval

Tags: sql, navision

I have the following code from Navision

```
PrintLine := FALSE;
LineTotalVendAmountDue := 0;
FOR i := 1 TO 5 DO BEGIN
  DtldVendLedgEntry.SETCURRENTKEY("Vendor No.","Initial Entry Due Date");
  DtldVendLedgEntry.SETRANGE("Vendor No.","No.");
  DtldVendLedgEntry.SETRANGE("Initial Entry Due Date",PeriodStartDate[i],PeriodStartDate[i + 1] - 1);
  DtldVendLedgEntry.CALCSUMS("Amount (LCY)");
  VendBalanceDue[i] := DtldVendLedgEntry."Amount (LCY)";
  VendBalanceDueLCY[i] := DtldVendLedgEntry."Amount (LCY)";
  IF VendBalanceDue[i] <> 0 THEN
    PrintLine := TRUE;
  LineTotalVendAmountDue := LineTotalVendAmountDue + VendBalanceDueLCY[i];
  TotalVendAmtDueLCY := TotalVendAmtDueLCY + VendBalanceDueLCY[i];
END;
```

I have to translate the code above into `SQL server` but I can't understand it. I am  a newbie with Navision.

Comment: Start by looking up individual instructions in the Navision documentation. Do you know what SETCURRENTKEY does? SETRANGE? Do you know what table the variable DtldVenLedgEntry relates to?
We're here to help you with specific questions, not do your work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard if even possible to translate to SQL given no context, but essentially:

For 5 date intervals (the start date of each specified in `PeriodStartDate` array) add up:

```
SELECT SUM([Amount (LCY)]) 
FROM [Company$Detailed Vendor Ledg. Entry] 
WHERE [Vendor No.] = $1 -- particular Vendor No.
AND [Initial Entry Due Date] BETWEEN $2 and $3 -- period start/end, inclusive
```

`LineTotalVendAmountDue` is set to the total of 5 intervals for the specific Vendor.

`TotalVendAmtDueLCY` is set to report grand total (presumably).

Comment: The query as described above has a wrong from table;
Detailed Cust. Ledg. Entry does not contain a Vendor No. 
You should use: Detailed Vendor Ledg. Entry